# How can I implement a massive update query that add n days to the date section of a DateTime field?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into DB and I have the following problem that I don't know how can be done in a smart way. I am woring using **MySql**

I have this **MeteoForecast** table:

```
CREATE TABLE MeteoForecast (
  id                       BigInt(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  localization_id          BigInt(20) NOT NULL,
  seasonal_forecast_id     BigInt(20),
  meteo_warning_id         BigInt(20),
  meteo_forecast_status_id BigInt(20),
  start_date               DateTime NOT NULL,
  end_date                 DateTime NOT NULL,
  min_temp                 TinyInt(4),
  max_temp                 TinyInt(4),
  icon_link                VarChar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  chances_of_rain          TinyInt(11),
  wind                     TinyInt(1),
  humidity                 TinyInt(11), 
  PRIMARY KEY (
      id
  )
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1872 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
ALTER TABLE MeteoForecast COMMENT = '';
```

Each record of this table represents a weather forecast.

At the moment contains some mocked test data that have to be massively update.

As you can see this table contains these 2 **DateTime** fields: **start_date** and **end_date** containing a forecast timeframe.

These field are **DateTime** because the timeframe is something like this:

```
start_date = 31/05/2018 12:00:00
end_date   = 31/05/2018 18:00:00
```

The problem is that I have a lot of records that after some times expires (because the days pass and these forecast are in the past...).

I want to do a massive update that change only the date section of the **start_date** and **end_date** fields of every record in my DB.

The problem is that I can't use a fixed date to do the update but I have to do something like this:

take the date section of the **start_date**/**end_date** field of the record that is updating and **add 10 days**.

So considering the previous example:

```
start_date = 31/05/2018 12:00:00
end_date   = 31/05/2018 18:00:00
```

have to become something like:

```
start_date = 10/06/2018 12:00:00
end_date   = 31/06/2018 18:00:00
```

How can I implement a massive update query doing something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to do a massive update that change only the date section of the
>   start_date and end_date fields of every record in my DB.
>
> The problem is that I can't use a fixed date to do the update but I
>   have to do something like this:
>
> take the date section of the start_date/end_date field of the record
>   that is updating and add 10 days.

You need to have a UPDATE query without WHERE clause to update every record in the database. 
 
This query will add 10 days to the existing data within the colums start_date and end_daye

```
UPDATE
 MeteoForecast 
SET
   MeteoForecast.start_date = MeteoForecast.start_date + INTERVAL 10 DAY
 , MeteoForecast.end_date = MeteoForecast.end_date + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want update start_date and add 10 days you can do:

```
UPDATE MeteoForecast SET start_date = start_date + INTERVAL 10 DAY;
```

For end_date if you want the last day of the month use the function LAST_DAY will return the last day of the month:

```
UPDATE MeteoForecast SET end_date = LAST_DAY(start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addtime()`:

```
update MeteoForecast
    set start_date = addtime(cast('2018-06-10' as datetime), time(start_date)),
        end_date = addtime(cast('2018-06-10' as datetime), time(end_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use DATE_ADD() function for this

```
UPDATE MeteoForecast SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY) , end_date = DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```